# Can't use PHP exec to run gsutil

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

For specific reasons, I need to run php exec() to fetch certain info from my bucket. For that, I installed gsutil following [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil_install) on both my local machine and on my production server. While on my local machine it worked wonders, I can't figure out why it doesn't run on production.
Thing is, while using SSH on my server, I can use gsutil to fetch the data I need no problems. It's not related to authentication because my bucket is currently configured as public(and i did not login on my local machine).

While tinkering around with this problem, I've found that www-data(the linux user) doesn't have access to /root/.config/gcloud, and i can't find a way to a) Change the folder location or b) Set permissions on that folder for www-data(While chmod/chown works, it doesn't change the output).

Both machines are running Ubuntu, local using 19.10 and server using 18.04

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Show you are starting `gsutil`. Remember it is a script so it requires launching a shell to run it in.

Comment: Can you elaborate more your issue? what error you get on the production server? If you give more details, it could be easy to help you.

Comment: @SamuelRomero Well, exec() returns nothing, and the error code is 1. When i run `sudo -u www-data gsutil`, it returns [this](https://pastebin.com/kBB0RuC2).

Comment: @JohnHanley Sorry but i couldn't understand your suggestion. I'm trying to run `exec("gsutil dosomething")` , and it works on my local test build

Comment: `gsutil` is not a program (executable). It is a batch or shell script depending on the OS.

Comment: It could be a better option to use the PHP client library https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/using-cloud-storage to upload files to a bucket, have you tried to use it?

Comment: @SamuelRomero i'm actually using another library for Laravel to handle file uploads. What i'm actually trying to get is the amount of disk usage on my bucket, so i'm trying to run `gsutil du -s gcs://mybucket/myfolder` withing PHP to store that info on my database.

Answer (score 0):

try to run gsutil with full path, probably gsutil installed to your /home/$USER/gsutil, you can copy folder into /var/www then open permission for www-data user and run exec like so

```
exec('python3 /var/www/gsutil/gsutil.py 2>&1', $output, $err);
```